# Как сохранить данные в Tables, только один элемент?

Tags: c#, wpf

За вопросу прошу прощения, может не правильно выставил, постараюсь исправить, как будет решена проблема (либо когда правильно сформулирую). Проблема такая: мне надо сохранить один элемент в datatable. Я обычно использовал все элементы. Поэтому использовал

```
Connection.ds.Tables["Сlient"].Rows[nomer-1].ItemArray = new object[] { nomer ,txtFamily.Text, txtImy.Text, 
                txtOtchestvo.Text, comboBox.Text, datePicker.Text, txtPhone.Text, txtEmail.Text};
```

Сейчас мне нужно сохранить только один элемент, который находится последним в таблице.
Я пробовал: `Connection.ds.Tables["Client"].Rows[nomer - 1].ItemArray[9] = new object[] { txtNewPassword.Text};`
и еще вот так:
Connection.ds.Tables["Client"].Rows[nomer - 1].ItemArray[9] = txtNewPassword.Text;

Но не один из способов не сработал. Может кто подсказать как решить эту проблему?

Comment: В программировании нет такого понятия: "не сработал". Есть конкретная ошибка/исключение и точное описание проблемы.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov ошибки нет. Проблема в том, что мне надо обновить данные. и обновляется только один элемент, а все остальные должны остаться так же. Все что я выше писал работает, но оно не делает то, что мне надо. Вот почему "не сработал". Если у вас есть совет буду вам благодарен как решить мою проблему.

Answer (score 0):

Решение есть, но оно кастыльное. Но оно мне помогло.

```
var b = Connection.ds.Tables["Client"].Rows[nomer - 1].ItemArray;
                b[9] =txtNewPassword.Text;
                Connection.ds.Tables["Client"].Rows[nomer - 1].ItemArray = b;
```